# N Queen, F# Getting Exception at last step

Tags: f#

I have written the solution to NQueen problem. It works as well, but It gets an exception at the last step.

Here is what I have written

```
let isNotDiagonal p c = 
    System.Math.Abs((int)((fst c) - (fst p))) <> System.Math.Abs((int)((snd c) - (snd p)));;

let isAllowed c = function
    | [] -> true
    | list -> List.forall (fun p -> (fst c) <> (fst p) && (snd c) <> (snd p) && (isNotDiagonal p c)) list;;

let comparePoints p1 p2 = 
    match p1, p2 with
    | p1, p2 when (fst p1 > fst p2) -> 1
    | p1, p2 when (fst p1 < fst p2) -> -1
    | p1, p2 when (fst p1 = fst p2) && (snd p1 > snd p2)-> 1
    | p1, p2 when (fst p1 = fst p2) && (snd p1 < snd p2) -> -1
    | p1, p2 when (fst p1 = fst p2) && (snd p1 = snd p2) -> 0
    | _, _ -> failwith "unknown pattern";;

let sort_list list = 
   List.sortWith comparePoints list;;

let print_list list = 
    printfn "%s" (List.fold (fun acc p -> acc + "(" + (fst p).ToString() + ", " + (snd p).ToString() + ")") "" (sort_list list));;

let rec moveQueen board pos list =
    match pos with 
    | (row, col) when row < board && col < board -> 
        if isAllowed pos list then
            moveQueen board (0, col + 1) (pos :: list)
        else
            moveQueen board (row + 1, col) (list)
    | (row, col) when row >= board && col < board ->
        moveQueen board (fst (List.head list) + 1, (snd (List.head list))) (List.tail list) 
    | (row, col) when col >= board ->    
        print_list list   
        moveQueen board (fst (List.head list) + 1, (snd (List.head list))) (List.tail list)
        ()
    | (_, _) -> failwith "unknown combination";;      

moveQueen 8 (0, 0) [];;
```

I get the following output

```
> (0, 0)(1, 6)(2, 4)(3, 7)(4, 1)(5, 3)(6, 5)(7, 2)
(0, 0)(1, 6)(2, 3)(3, 5)(4, 7)(5, 1)(6, 4)(7, 2)
(0, 0)(1, 5)(2, 7)(3, 2)(4, 6)(5, 3)(6, 1)(7, 4)
(0, 0)(1, 4)(2, 7)(3, 5)(4, 2)(5, 6)(6, 1)(7, 3)
(0, 5)(1, 0)(2, 4)(3, 1)(4, 7)(5, 2)(6, 6)(7, 3)
(0, 3)(1, 0)(2, 4)(3, 7)(4, 1)(5, 6)(6, 2)(7, 5)
(0, 4)(1, 0)(2, 7)(3, 3)(4, 1)(5, 6)(6, 2)(7, 5)
(0, 2)(1, 0)(2, 6)(3, 4)(4, 7)(5, 1)(6, 3)(7, 5)
(0, 4)(1, 0)(2, 3)(3, 5)(4, 7)(5, 1)(6, 6)(7, 2)
(0, 6)(1, 0)(2, 2)(3, 7)(4, 5)(5, 3)(6, 1)(7, 4)
(0, 4)(1, 0)(2, 7)(3, 5)(4, 2)(5, 6)(6, 1)(7, 3)
(0, 3)(1, 0)(2, 4)(3, 7)(4, 5)(5, 2)(6, 6)(7, 1)
(0, 1)(1, 5)(2, 0)(3, 6)(4, 3)(5, 7)(6, 2)(7, 4)
(0, 4)(1, 2)(2, 0)(3, 6)(4, 1)(5, 7)(6, 5)(7, 3)
(0, 7)(1, 2)(2, 0)(3, 5)(4, 1)(5, 4)(6, 6)(7, 3)
(0, 3)(1, 5)(2, 0)(3, 4)(4, 1)(5, 7)(6, 2)(7, 6)
(0, 4)(1, 6)(2, 0)(3, 3)(4, 1)(5, 7)(6, 5)(7, 2)
(0, 5)(1, 2)(2, 0)(3, 7)(4, 3)(5, 1)(6, 6)(7, 4)
(0, 4)(1, 2)(2, 0)(3, 5)(4, 7)(5, 1)(6, 3)(7, 6)
(0, 5)(1, 2)(2, 0)(3, 7)(4, 4)(5, 1)(6, 3)(7, 6)
(0, 3)(1, 7)(2, 0)(3, 2)(4, 5)(5, 1)(6, 6)(7, 4)
(0, 7)(1, 3)(2, 0)(3, 2)(4, 5)(5, 1)(6, 6)(7, 4)
(0, 3)(1, 7)(2, 0)(3, 4)(4, 6)(5, 1)(6, 5)(7, 2)
(0, 3)(1, 6)(2, 0)(3, 7)(4, 4)(5, 1)(6, 5)(7, 2)
(0, 5)(1, 3)(2, 0)(3, 4)(4, 7)(5, 1)(6, 6)(7, 2)
(0, 5)(1, 2)(2, 0)(3, 6)(4, 4)(5, 7)(6, 1)(7, 3)
(0, 6)(1, 2)(2, 0)(3, 5)(4, 7)(5, 4)(6, 1)(7, 3)
(0, 4)(1, 6)(2, 0)(3, 2)(4, 7)(5, 5)(6, 3)(7, 1)
(0, 1)(1, 4)(2, 6)(3, 0)(4, 2)(5, 7)(6, 5)(7, 3)
(0, 1)(1, 7)(2, 5)(3, 0)(4, 2)(5, 4)(6, 6)(7, 3)
(0, 5)(1, 1)(2, 6)(3, 0)(4, 2)(5, 4)(6, 7)(7, 3)
(0, 6)(1, 1)(2, 3)(3, 0)(4, 7)(5, 4)(6, 2)(7, 5)
(0, 7)(1, 1)(2, 3)(3, 0)(4, 6)(5, 4)(6, 2)(7, 5)
(0, 4)(1, 1)(2, 7)(3, 0)(4, 3)(5, 6)(6, 2)(7, 5)
(0, 5)(1, 1)(2, 6)(3, 0)(4, 3)(5, 7)(6, 4)(7, 2)
(0, 4)(1, 1)(2, 5)(3, 0)(4, 6)(5, 3)(6, 7)(7, 2)
(0, 2)(1, 4)(2, 6)(3, 0)(4, 3)(5, 1)(6, 7)(7, 5)
(0, 5)(1, 3)(2, 6)(3, 0)(4, 7)(5, 1)(6, 4)(7, 2)
(0, 4)(1, 7)(2, 3)(3, 0)(4, 6)(5, 1)(6, 5)(7, 2)
(0, 2)(1, 5)(2, 7)(3, 0)(4, 4)(5, 6)(6, 1)(7, 3)
(0, 6)(1, 4)(2, 2)(3, 0)(4, 5)(5, 7)(6, 1)(7, 3)
(0, 5)(1, 3)(2, 6)(3, 0)(4, 2)(5, 4)(6, 1)(7, 7)
(0, 4)(1, 7)(2, 3)(3, 0)(4, 2)(5, 5)(6, 1)(7, 6)
(0, 2)(1, 5)(2, 3)(3, 0)(4, 7)(5, 4)(6, 6)(7, 1)
(0, 2)(1, 5)(2, 7)(3, 0)(4, 3)(5, 6)(6, 4)(7, 1)
(0, 4)(1, 6)(2, 3)(3, 0)(4, 2)(5, 7)(6, 5)(7, 1)
(0, 1)(1, 5)(2, 7)(3, 2)(4, 0)(5, 3)(6, 6)(7, 4)
(0, 1)(1, 4)(2, 6)(3, 3)(4, 0)(5, 7)(6, 5)(7, 2)
(0, 1)(1, 6)(2, 4)(3, 7)(4, 0)(5, 3)(6, 5)(7, 2)
(0, 6)(1, 1)(2, 5)(3, 2)(4, 0)(5, 3)(6, 7)(7, 4)
(0, 7)(1, 1)(2, 4)(3, 2)(4, 0)(5, 6)(6, 3)(7, 5)
(0, 3)(1, 1)(2, 7)(3, 5)(4, 0)(5, 2)(6, 4)(7, 6)
(0, 3)(1, 1)(2, 6)(3, 4)(4, 0)(5, 7)(6, 5)(7, 2)
(0, 2)(1, 5)(2, 1)(3, 6)(4, 0)(5, 3)(6, 7)(7, 4)
(0, 2)(1, 4)(2, 1)(3, 7)(4, 0)(5, 6)(6, 3)(7, 5)
(0, 5)(1, 7)(2, 1)(3, 3)(4, 0)(5, 6)(6, 4)(7, 2)
(0, 2)(1, 7)(2, 3)(3, 6)(4, 0)(5, 5)(6, 1)(7, 4)
(0, 2)(1, 4)(2, 7)(3, 3)(4, 0)(5, 6)(6, 1)(7, 5)
(0, 5)(1, 2)(2, 6)(3, 3)(4, 0)(5, 7)(6, 1)(7, 4)
(0, 5)(1, 2)(2, 4)(3, 6)(4, 0)(5, 3)(6, 1)(7, 7)
(0, 5)(1, 2)(2, 4)(3, 7)(4, 0)(5, 3)(6, 1)(7, 6)
(0, 3)(1, 7)(2, 4)(3, 2)(4, 0)(5, 6)(6, 1)(7, 5)
(0, 3)(1, 6)(2, 4)(3, 2)(4, 0)(5, 5)(6, 7)(7, 1)
(0, 3)(1, 5)(2, 7)(3, 2)(4, 0)(5, 6)(6, 4)(7, 1)
(0, 1)(1, 3)(2, 5)(3, 7)(4, 2)(5, 0)(6, 6)(7, 4)
(0, 3)(1, 1)(2, 4)(3, 7)(4, 5)(5, 0)(6, 2)(7, 6)
(0, 3)(1, 1)(2, 7)(3, 4)(4, 6)(5, 0)(6, 2)(7, 5)
(0, 2)(1, 6)(2, 1)(3, 7)(4, 4)(5, 0)(6, 3)(7, 5)
(0, 2)(1, 5)(2, 1)(3, 4)(4, 7)(5, 0)(6, 6)(7, 3)
(0, 2)(1, 5)(2, 1)(3, 6)(4, 4)(5, 0)(6, 7)(7, 3)
(0, 4)(1, 6)(2, 1)(3, 5)(4, 2)(5, 0)(6, 3)(7, 7)
(0, 4)(1, 6)(2, 1)(3, 5)(4, 2)(5, 0)(6, 7)(7, 3)
(0, 6)(1, 3)(2, 1)(3, 4)(4, 7)(5, 0)(6, 2)(7, 5)
(0, 6)(1, 3)(2, 1)(3, 7)(4, 5)(5, 0)(6, 2)(7, 4)
(0, 4)(1, 6)(2, 1)(3, 3)(4, 7)(5, 0)(6, 2)(7, 5)
(0, 2)(1, 5)(2, 7)(3, 1)(4, 3)(5, 0)(6, 6)(7, 4)
(0, 6)(1, 2)(2, 7)(3, 1)(4, 4)(5, 0)(6, 5)(7, 3)
(0, 3)(1, 6)(2, 4)(3, 1)(4, 5)(5, 0)(6, 2)(7, 7)
(0, 3)(1, 5)(2, 7)(3, 1)(4, 6)(5, 0)(6, 2)(7, 4)
(0, 4)(1, 2)(2, 7)(3, 3)(4, 6)(5, 0)(6, 5)(7, 1)
(0, 1)(1, 6)(2, 2)(3, 5)(4, 7)(5, 4)(6, 0)(7, 3)
(0, 3)(1, 1)(2, 6)(3, 2)(4, 5)(5, 7)(6, 0)(7, 4)
(0, 4)(1, 1)(2, 3)(3, 5)(4, 7)(5, 2)(6, 0)(7, 6)
(0, 2)(1, 6)(2, 1)(3, 7)(4, 5)(5, 3)(6, 0)(7, 4)
(0, 5)(1, 3)(2, 1)(3, 7)(4, 4)(5, 6)(6, 0)(7, 2)
(0, 5)(1, 2)(2, 6)(3, 1)(4, 3)(5, 7)(6, 0)(7, 4)
(0, 5)(1, 2)(2, 6)(3, 1)(4, 7)(5, 4)(6, 0)(7, 3)
(0, 3)(1, 6)(2, 2)(3, 7)(4, 1)(5, 4)(6, 0)(7, 5)
(0, 3)(1, 1)(2, 6)(3, 2)(4, 5)(5, 7)(6, 4)(7, 0)
(0, 4)(1, 1)(2, 3)(3, 6)(4, 2)(5, 7)(6, 5)(7, 0)
(0, 2)(1, 4)(2, 1)(3, 7)(4, 5)(5, 3)(6, 6)(7, 0)
(0, 2)(1, 5)(2, 3)(3, 1)(4, 7)(5, 4)(6, 6)(7, 0)

System.ArgumentException: The input list was empty.
Parameter name: list
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.Head[T](FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at FSI_0020.moveQueen(Int32 board, Int32 pos_0, Int32 pos_1, FSharpList`1 list)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0021>.$FSI_0021.main@()
   at main@dm()
Stopped due to error
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting the exception.

Also, how to I return a list of lists? where each list is a solution?

My objective behind sort and compare method is that I should be able to eliminate duplicate solutions and be able to find just the unique solutions for various board sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the exception because you are using List.head on a empty list, but that is not the real problem here, the problem is there are no end condition for moveQueen.

You have to take care of what happen when it have found all solutions, in you code it will try to get the head of the empty list and fail.

One way to do it (i have not test that much) are:

```
let rec moveQueen board pos list : (int * int) list list =
    match pos with 
    | (row, col) when row < board && col < board -> 
        if isAllowed pos list then
            moveQueen board (0, col + 1) (pos :: list)
        else
            moveQueen board (row + 1, col) (list)
    | (row, _) when row >= board && List.isEmpty list ->  [] 
    | (row, col) when row >= board && col < board ->
        moveQueen board (fst (List.head list) + 1, (snd (List.head list))) (List.tail list) 
    | (_, col) when col >= board ->    
         list::moveQueen board (fst (List.head list) + 1, (snd (List.head list))) (List.tail list)    
    | (row, col) -> failwith ("unknown combination (" + row.ToString() + ", " + col.ToString() + ")");;  

List.iter print_list (moveQueen 8 (0, 0) []);;
```